# Download documents in a zip from a page using in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, publishing-page, jsom

I have created a product page in SharePoint Online Pages Library. It has some standard field, e-g **Title** and **Comments**. It also has a Content Query WebPart that displays a list of linked files stored in a document library, Pages library and Documents library have lookup column relation.

I want to have a download button on the page to download all linked files in a zip.

I am looking for JSOM/JavaScript solution but I can also consider sandbox solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create array of file URL you want to archive.
Next for each file read the byte array.
Then use [jzip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) library to create zip file in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link : https://www.dsouzajoel.com/2015/12/06/download-selected-files-as-zip-file-using-jszip/

You may need to rework on the UI part. But the functionality will work

Comment: See last comment on other answer